# Search Plus Plugin: How to sort facets?

Tags: plugin-searchplus

I'm using the Search Plus plugin with Craft, it's been a great help! 
I have 2 questions I need help with, as the Search Plus docs are not too clear so far:

1. I have a search page with filters (facets) in place, however these
   facets are arranged according to search count by default. I want to
   sort them by alphabetical order instead, and I've seen that it is
   possible with Algolia, but I need help to do that with Search Plus.
2. Upon clicking on a filter checkbox, the other filters disappear. How
   do I trigger them to still appear but with a different CSS class
   applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problems as you and I believe I've solved it, but it may be different for your specific use case.

1. There may be a way to control this with the `init` options but I wasn't able to find a way to do it, so I just edited the `searchplus.js` code directly in the `searchplus` folder. Look for something like `e.getFacetValues(i,{sortBy:["isRefined:desc","count:desc"]})` and change it to `e.getFacetValues(i,{sortBy:["name:asc"]})` instead (you can leave the `isRefined:desc` part at the front as well if you would like the filtered options to automatically populate to the top of the list). Keep in mind that changing the `js` file is a global change which would affect other faceted forms if you have more than one on your site.
2. When you define the facets in your `init` code: `$(this).searchplus({facets: ['facet1', 'facet2'],});`, replace `facets` with `disjunctiveFacets` and you should stop seeing filters disappear from the facet you're selecting (see faceting options on [the Search Plus docs](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/searchplus/usage/javascript-setup/helper-reference#facet-parameters). The other facet's filters *will* disappear though depending on if there are valid matches or not, but it will at least prevent the other filters from your *selected* facet from disappearing immediately.